# Merge and consolidate an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, enumerable

I am trying to take this array of hash values...

```
items => [{:name=>"item a", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
 {:name=>"item b", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
 {:name=>"item a", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
 {:name=>"item b", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
 {:name=>"item c", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
 {:name=>"item d", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]}]
```

And get an output that looks like the following...

```
items => [{:name=>"item a", :count=>2, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004", "51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
     {:name=>"item b", :count=>2, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004, 51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
     {:name=>"item c", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
     {:name=>"item d", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]}]
```

I want to group by name and consolidate the count, and contributors as illustrated above.  How do I do that?  Group_by, reduce?  Can someone post an example?

Comment: please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: What is `items =>`? That part makes your expression invalid.

Comment: Do you mean `items = [ ... ]` ?

Comment: You selected @falsetru's answer (good choice), but didn't upvote his answer. Just wanted yoy to know you can do both, in case you were unaware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
items = [
  {:name=>"item a", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
  {:name=>"item b", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
  {:name=>"item a", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
  {:name=>"item b", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
  {:name=>"item c", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
  {:name=>"item d", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]}
]
items.group_by { |h| h[:name] }.map { |key, hs|
  {:name => key,
   :count => hs.inject(0) { |c, h| c + h[:count] },
   :contributors => hs.map { |h| h[:contributors] }
  }
}

# => [{:name=>"item a", :count=>2,
#      :contributors=>[["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"], ["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]]},
#     {:name=>"item b", :count=>2,
#      :contributors=>[["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"], ["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]]},
#     {:name=>"item c", :count=>1, :contributors=>[["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]]},
#     {:name=>"item d", :count=>1, :contributors=>[["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]]}]
```

Comment: Considering that I initially posted the same solution (then seeing yours was already up, deleted it), +1 is a no-brainer.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and since it was the first answer, I've accepted it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Congrats on hitting 100k!

Answer (score 1):

I initially posted another solution, only to find that @falsetru had already posted a nearly identical answer, so it was back to the drawing board.  Not quite, actually, because for this type of problem there are two common lines of attack, so I then went with the other one.

```
def combine(items)
  items.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
    h.update({ g[:name] => g }) do |k,ov,nv|
      { name: g[:name], count: (ov[:count] + nv[:count]),
        contributors: (ov[:contributors] + nv[:contributors]) }
    end
  end.values
end
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that takes a block for determining the value for each key that is shared by the two hashes being merged.

Note I allow `:count` to have values other than `1` and `:contributors` to have values (arrays) containing more than one value.

```
combine(items)
 #=>[{:name=>"item a", :count=>2,
 #    :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004", "51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
 #   {:name=>"item b", :count=>2,
 #    :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004", "51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
 #   {:name=>"item c", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]},
 #   {:name=>"item d", :count=>1, :contributors=>["51db6d58bd02861e96000004"]}]
```

Comment: Thanks Cary, this seems to be a great approach as well and was well explained.